# About HTML capability

Tags: html

Hey all here is one question from Gate exam which i found a bit confusing:

```
HTML (Hyper Text Markup Language) has language elements which permit
certain actions other than describing the structure of the web document. Which
one of the following actions is NOT supported by pure HTML (without any server
or client side scripting) pages?
(A) Embed web objects from different sites into the same page
(B) Refresh the page automatically after a specified interval
(C) Automatically redirect to another page upon download
(D) Display the client time as part of the page
```

I think it is either C or D. But not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: D <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://www.the-domain-you-want-to-redirect-to.com"> (Can redirect to another page from this page)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A) That's what the `<object>` element is for.

B) The ancient `<meta http-equiv="refresh">` tag.

C) If "upon download" means upon download completion, it's obviously impossible. Also, without JavaScript, the only ways to navigate anywhere are form submit buttons and links, neither of which can be used to navigate to two targets. You can, however, link to a page where you use a construct like `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=download.binary" />`(or an 0x0-`<iframe>` with the download source) to achieve this.

D) Obviously impossible without JavaScript - you have simply no idea about the user's time when you send your reply.

Comment: I suppose "upon download" means "as soon as the HTML document is downloaded into the browser", which I suppose plays on a variation of B.

Comment: Thanks phihag :) I also think so. But in answer sheet, i found on some gate related forum, it to be B. which i think absolutely impossible. So i think there must be a misprint in that place.

Answer (score 0):

**We can display a clock which will be showing the local time of the client computer by using JavaScript. Note that this time displayed is taken from user computer and not from the server.**

So, Option D is Not Valid For This Question. (Answer is D.)  :) :)